React npx create-react-app hangs and fails/aborts
I am trying to install a MERN stack to learn the stack. I have a VPS running Ubuntu 22.04 where I have installed node v20.12.2 and npm 10.5.0.
When I run npx create-react-app myapp, here is the output:

Creating a new React app in /home/merncy/mern/myapp.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

(#########⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂⠂) ⠴ idealTree:@babel/core: sill placeDep ROOT semver@7.6.0 O
Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting myapp/ from /home/merncy/mern
Done.


Try running that command stand alone

Node 20 may be too new for CRA... try an older version, like Node 16.

FYI create-react-app is a dead project. Try Vite as a modern alternative
